# Using the WordPress Media Library and returning the Attachment ID rather than URL?

Tags: jquery, media-library, thickbox

I'm currently using some JS to pop open the WordPress Media Library in a thickbox container and return the URL of a selected image, then display it.

```
window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
    imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
    jQuery('#upload_image-' + id_to_pass).val(imgurl);

    output_code = '<img class="media_display" src="' + imgurl + '" />';
    jQuery(output_code).appendTo('#media_display-' + id_to_pass);

    tb_remove();
}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to return the attachment ID instead?

I would like to use the image's description and caption fields, which I won't be able to do (easily) if I can only access the image URL from the Media Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/hijacking-the-wordpress-media-library-overlay/

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for that. I've already tried SLT's plugin but its "Remove" upload functionality isn't clear to the user: it doesn't remove the preview image, it just clears the hidden input's value:

`// Wipe form values when remove checkboxes are checked
  $( '.slt-fs-button:first' ).parents( 'form' ).submit( function() {
   $( '.slt-fs-remove:checked' ).each( function() {
    $( this ).siblings( 'input.slt-fs-value' ).val( '' );
   });
  });`

If you have any idea how to solve that, you'd be a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

It's more a hack than a solution. You could use a regex to extract the attachment ID from the `wp-image-` class. Add the following snippet to your `window.send_to_editor` function.

```
$classes = jQuery('img', html).attr('class');
$id = $classes.replace(/(.*?)wp-image-/, '');
```